# create_pandas_dataframe_agent() over multiple CSV dataframes

Tags: python, openai-api, agent, langchain, large-language-model

Using the example from the **langchain** documentation(https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/toolkits/pandas) and despite having tried all kinds of things, I am not able to **create the agent over 2 CSV file** (I precise that the agent works fine on a single CSV).

```
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
import pandas as pd

# Import input data 
df = pd.read_csv("titanic.csv")

# Create a second pandas dataframe
df1 = df.copy()
df1["Age"] = df1["Age"].fillna(df1["Age"].mean())

# Run the agent over multiple dataframe
agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(OpenAI(temperature=0, model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo', deployment_id="chat"), [df, df1], verbose=True)
agent.run("how many rows in the age column are different?")
```

**This is the error I get** : "ValueError: Expected pandas object, got <class 'list'>".
Does anyone know if the documentation is up to date? Any idea to overcome this ? Here is a screenshot if it can help...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this error

```
"ValueError: Expected pandas object, got <class 'list'>"
```

most likely because you did not initialize `df` correctly (maybe you passed a wrong path)

```
df = pd.read_csv("titanic.csv")
```

if you load it correctly, you would get a different error:

[image]

if you remove `deployment_id="chat"` your code will work:

[image]

Comment: Surprisingly, I did exactly what you suggested, I checked the import of my CSV files and removed the deployment_id, but I still get the same error. Could you please tell me which version of langchain and pandas packages you used for your example?

Comment: your file might be corrupted or make sure path is correct

Comment: you can download `titanic.csv` https://github.com/datasciencedojo/datasets/blob/master/titanic.csv

Comment: I updated my post with a screenshot if you have 5 minutes to have a look,. Thanks again for your advice but unfortunately it really seems that it is not related to the csv file. I can import and see it in the visualizer tool and it doesn´t seems to be corrupted. And I precise the agent set up works perfectly when I only use df ( one unique csv file) . It would really help if you could give me the package versions you are using :)

Comment: `langchain    0.0.247` and `pandas        1.4.4`

Comment: what is your os? `df = pd.read_csv("titanic.csv")` is not resolving.  maybe you should add slash. `df = pd.read_csv("./titanic.csv")` if you are on windows "\"

Comment: hi ! Thanks a lot for you help ! It is now working with the pandas version 1.5.3. It seems the most recent versions of the pandas package doesn´t fit with the create_pandas_dataframe_agent() function